# What does this do: *f = Foo(value)

Tags: go

I found this implementation of `database/sql.Scanner` interface, but I don't really understand it?

It's possible to compile

I get the part that `Foo` is an integer and it has the method `Scan`

1. The `Scan` method returns `error` but how can `fmt.Errorf("Invalid database type: %T %v", value, value)` be returned? It's not an error or?
2. What does `*f = Foo(value)` do? When you pass this type to `rows.Scan()` it will call `Foo.Scan()`? And if the type is the expected `int64` it will call itself `Foo(value)`?

## code

```
type Foo int

// Scan implements the database/sql.Scanner interface
func (f *Foo) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    switch value := value.(type) {
    case int64:
        *f = Foo(value)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("Invalid database type: %T %v", value, value)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `fmt.Errorf(format, args)` returns an error value created with `errors.New(str)` where `str` is the formatted string (your error message).
2. The line `*f = Foo(value)` converts the `int64` value to the type `Foo` and assigns it to the method receiver (note that `f` is a pointer).